# I am trying to apply groupBy on a exploded column in Spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I/P:

Employee DF

```
Name | Project 

| A  | p1,p2

| B   | p1
      
| C   | p2
```

O/P:

Project DF

```
| proj| Count|


| p1  | 2            |

| p2   | 2          |
```

I need to count the number of employees working on each project. I tried below snippet but it's not giving me the correct answer:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['A', 'p1, p2'], ['B', 'p1'], ['C', 'p2']]), ["name", "project"])
 
df2 = df.withColumn('proj',explode(split(df['project'],",")))

df2.groupBy('proj').count().show()
```

My output

```
| proj| Count|

| p2  | 1  

| p2   | 1  

| p1   | 2
```

I don't know why it is not performing groupBy on p2.

Comment: Hey, this shouldn't be too difficult to solve but you are more likely to get a response if you format your question a little better. Take a look at some formatting guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

There is leading whitespace before one of the p2's so they aren't grouped together in your groupby operation

```
>>> df2.groupBy('proj').count().collect()
[Row(proj=' p2', count=1), Row(proj='p2', count=1), Row(proj='p1', count=2)]
```

To solve this, remove the whitespace between the comma separating p1 and p2.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['A', 'p1,p2'], ['B', 'p1'], ['C', 'p2']]), ["name", "project"])
>>> df2 = df.withColumn('proj',explode(split(df['project'],",")))
>>> df2.groupBy('proj').count().collect()
[Row(proj='p2', count=2), Row(proj='p1', count=2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by a comma followed with a space, instead of a comma:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['A', 'p1, p2'], ['B', 'p1'], ['C', 'p2']]), ["name", "project"])
 
df2 = df.withColumn('proj',explode(split(df['project'],", ")))   # <-- comma with space

df2.groupBy('proj').count().show()
+----+-----+
|proj|count|
+----+-----+
|  p2|    2|
|  p1|    2|
+----+-----+
```